# Как строить проект с помощью MVC

Tags: java, android

Объясните,  как лучше строить проект по шаблону MVC.
Например,  у меня есть приложение,  с 3 переключателями страниц.
На первой чат,  на вторая информация ,третья приват.
Лучше делить на модули?Что бы не заграмождать один активити кодом, контроллерами и моделями?

Comment: толковый выбор приходит с опытом а к нему приводит выбор безтолковый!

Comment: Отлично,  очень информативно.

Comment: Для андроида вроде MVP используют, MVC для немного других задачь.

Comment: Что вы хотите услышать? Информация по паттернам в интеренете уйма, читайте и реализуйте у себя. Я бы советовал MVP или MVVM. Есть еще MVI это более свежий паттерн. Вообщя суть всех этих паттернов как и в общем Clean Architecture разделить весь код на слои, что бы при изменении логики в одной части кода, не надо было менять код во всем проекте. Вот например статья для общего развития https://habrahabr.ru/post/215605/

Comment: Да больше интересовало другое.

Comment: Да больше интересовало,а как лучше...если вижу что кода будет много,луше модули создавать отдельно или отдельно классы?

Comment: Этот сайт создан для решения конкретных проблем, у Вас вопрос очень размыт и судя по самому вопросу вы не читали то о чем спрашиваете. Почитайте про MVP, в гайдах все расписано. Как  и зачем разделять классы.

Comment: паттерн MVC реализуется самой системой Android "из коробки", где M (model) - данные, V (view) - разметка, и С (controller) - активити. А вот как организовать код, чтобы в том же контроллере (активити) не было "мусора" - ваша головная боль и про архитектуры целые книги пишут, вам же их **надо читать**, потому что в один ответ на этом ресурсе вам никто такой объем знаний в голову не положит.

Comment: Вот еще одна статья здесь только про андроид https://habrahabr.ru/company/redmadrobot/blog/257861/